# How can I avoid the name of Chapter auto write into toc?

Tags: table-of-contents

There are two contents in my TeX: 'toc'(system-defined) and 'toch'(user-defined) as what I show in the below example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\chcontentsname{CONTENTS}
\newcommand\tableofchcontents{
   \section*{\chcontentsname}
   \@starttoc{toch}
   }
\makeatother

\newcommand{\BiSection}[2]
{   \section{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toch}{section}{\protect\numberline{\csname thesection\endcsname}#2}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\tableofchcontents

\BiSection{S1}{SECTION1}
\BiSection{S2}{SECTION2}


\end{document}
```

Here is the situation:
I want to to make the title of sections coincides with the user-defined content(toch) while it auto coincides with system-defined content(toc) now.

Is there any way to control the process of '\addcontentsline{toc}' in command '\section' artificially? Like to make some '\renewcommand' to prevent the autogeneration of 'toc'?

Comment: Welcome. Could you please add a minimal example?

Comment: I _really_ don't understand what you want to achieve. Would you please clarify?

Comment: Do you want to change the behavior of `\addcontentsline` command to your `\tableofchcontents`?

Comment: Yes, but I also need to change the behavior of `\addcontentsline` command of `\section`. In conclusion, I want to exchange the content of `toc` and `toch`.